# Flash + Internet Explorer 9 = Crash

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, internet-explorer-9, adobe-flash

With the [release of Internet Explorer 9](http://Windows.Microsoft.com/en-US/internet-Explorer/downloads/ie-9/worldwide-languages) I decided to give it a go. It really is great and integrates nicely with VS 2010.

However when ever I try to access a page with flash I get an instant crash. I have tried uninstalling flash and reinstalling but no joy.

Sys: Windows 7 64-bit SP1

Anyone else getting this problem?

Comment: Flash Player version?

Comment: Latest (10.2.152.32). Just found out it works in IE9 64bit version OK with beta flash

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the problem you described for some time now. The following steps finally solved the problem for me.

Open IE, click on the gear on the top right. Select internet options, then go to the advanced tab. Click the option that resets the advanced settings, click apply. Restart IE.

I found this solution buried in a bunch of comments on the Adobe air and flash player team blog. The commenter actually used it to solve a different problem with Flash (Flash content is being displayed in the upper left corner of the screen), but it worked as well for the crash problem I was experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

crash entire computer or just the browser? any error message? Did you reboot after you reinstalled the newest flash?

Googling found this thread:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/itproxpsp/thread/6a8b0219-1764-417a-a38c-372266a6e10a

From it, one guy suggests 3rd party addons (mouse gestures, toolbars) might not play well with flash. He also suggests using adobe's special flash removal tool... it might be your reinstall didn't replace a few old leftover bits.

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14157.html

Comment: Was only crashing the browser, nothing else. Like I say, the 64bit version doesn't have the same issue. I tired restarting also.

Comment: I have no idea then, unless it really is javascript related. If enough people have the problem, windows will probably patch it through windows update. Good that it works in 64 bit anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've had my previously rock solid setup, 3.2 GHz Phenom X4 w/ 16 GB of RAM and Windows 7 Pro x64 bit scretch to a halt (not even a BSOD) in the middle of flash videos (youtube, news broadcasts...etc). It's probably a bug in Adobe's x64 flash player and a bug in IE9's hardware acceleration that causes low-level exceptions to occur which halts the computer.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, I found it happens on pages with javascript. I updated java and the problem was solved.

Comment: Java is _not related_ to JavaScript.